# Unity Google Play Services: Authentication Failed always:

Tags: c#, authentication, google-play-services, google-play-games, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with authenticate. The authenticate always fail and I can't understand the cause (not only fail in the editor, in my device too). Here is the code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using GooglePlayGames;
 using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
 using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
 using UnityEngine.Analytics;

 public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

 public Text record;

 /**
     Menu when the player isn´t authenticate
  */
 public GameObject signIn;

 public GameObject test;

 void Awake()
 {
     PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
     PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
     GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = false;
     GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
 }

 void Start()
 {
     Advertisement.Initialize ("CORRECT_NUMBER", true);


     if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("record"))
     {
         record.text = "Record actual: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record");
         Analytics.CustomEvent ("Start Play", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Record", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record")} });
         if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
         {
             Social.ReportScore (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("record"), "CORRECT_CODE", (bool success) => { });
         }
     } else {
             record.text = "Consigue un record!!";
     }

     if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
     {
         signIn.SetActive (false);           
     }
     test.SetActive (false);
 }

 public void OnPlay()
 {
     ShowAd ();
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Play");
     Time.timeScale = 0;
 }

 public void OnArchievements()
 {
     if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
         Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
     } else {
         Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
             if (success) {
                 Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();           
             }
         });
     }

 }

 public void OnMatching()
 {
     if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
         Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
     } else {
         Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
             if (success) {
                 Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();        
             }
         });
     }
 }

 public void OnExit()
 {
     Analytics.CustomEvent ("Stop Play", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Record", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record")} });
     Application.Quit();
 }

 public void SignIn()
 {
     Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { 
         if (success)
         {
             Debug.Log ("Sign in");
             signIn.SetActive (false);
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.Log ("Fail for some reason...");
             test.SetActive (true);
         }

     });

 }

 public void Later()
 {
     signIn.SetActive (false);
 }

 public void ShowAd()
 {
     if (Advertisement.IsReady())
     {
         Advertisement.Show();
     }
 }
 }
```

The object "test" is only a white box that appears to know the authentication fail. The console don't show me any type of error, so I don't know where find the problem... Any idea what's the problem? PD: I use version 0.9.34 and Unity 5.3.5f1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Alejandro, I think that you are having 2 issues here: 1: you forgot to authenticate the user-> Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication); what the GPGS does is creating a ISocialPlatform and set it the active one. 2- You should do the "Awake()" part in the "Start()". Let me know.

Comment: Sorry for your example this would be the correct way to do it: authenticate the user when she/he hits sing in button-> Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(SignIn);

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you (it's the first time I try to use google play service). I change the awake part like you say, but I don't know how do the authentication you said. Must I call a method in the Authenticate's "params"?? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: And thanks very much for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem. 
I am going to write the response here because it may be quite long.

Unity has the default ISocialPlatform set to Apple. Doing the "PlayGamesClientConfiguration" you change the default ISocialPlatform to Google+.

My comment was talking about your Awake() function. I recommended you to put it in Start() as follows:

```
    void Start()
         {
    //added code
     PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
         PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
         GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = false;


         //GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Activate (); //this is wrong

      //WHAT YOU ARE MISSING
      PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
      //END OF WHAT YOU ARE MISSING

             Advertisement.Initialize ("CORRECT_NUMBER", true);


             if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("record"))
             {
                 record.text = "Record actual: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record");
                 Analytics.CustomEvent ("Start Play", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Record", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record")} });

      //you should do this once the user is authenticated and logged in
                 if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
                 {
                     Social.ReportScore (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("record"), "CORRECT_CODE", (bool success) => { });
                 }
             } else {
                     record.text = "Consigue un record!!";
             }

             if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
             {
                 signIn.SetActive (false);           
             }
             test.SetActive (false);
         }
```

Then, you can create a button in the inspector inside your scene and call this:

```
 public void SignIn()
 {
     Social.localUser.Authenticate( ProcessAuthentication)
 }
```

The CallBackFunction is a void function that takes in a bool. (You were doing this correctly) I like making my code readable and easy to understand.

```
    void ProcessAuthentication (bool success) 
        {
            if (true == success) 
            {
                Debug.Log ("AUTHENTICATED!");
                if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
                 {
                     Social.ReportScore (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("record"), "CORRECT_CODE", (bool success) => { });
                 }
             } else {
                     record.text = "Consigue un record!!";
             }

             if (Social.localUser.authenticated) 
             {
                 signIn.SetActive (false);   

                 //EDIT: you need to load the achievements to use them
                 Social.LoadAchievements (ProcessLoadedAchievements);

                Social.LoadScores(leaderboardID, CALLBACK) // Callback has to be a Action<IScore[]> callback
            }
             test.SetActive (false);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to authenticate");
                signIn.SetActive (true);
            }
        }



void ProcessLoadedAchievements (IAchievement[] achievements) {
        if (achievements.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Error: no achievements found");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("Got " + achievements.Length + " achievements");
        }
    }
```

Let me know. 
(I can explain it to you in Spanish too if you want)
Saludos!

Comment: Ok, I think I understand unless last method (ProcessAuthentication), where do I call it? Or is a method of the engine(like the start method)? Really you help me if you write in spanish jajaja. Again, thanks a lot!! PD: I really don't do what you say because I'm not at home.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the ProcessAuthentication  function. I wanted to give you an example of a CallBackFunction. You can rename it as you wish. Thanks.

Comment: I write a answer because I needed show you the code, and in comment I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I follow this tutorial: [google tutorial in GitHub (README)](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and the tutorial don't say I must implement that method, in fact, when I read it, I understand these method are part of the engine.
Here is my new code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.Analytics;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

public Text record;

public GameObject test;

/**
    Indicador del jugador de que no ha iniciado sesión, y no podrá acceder al  ranking ni a los logros.
 */
public GameObject signIn;

void Start()
{       
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    Advertisement.Initialize ("NUMBER", true);
    test.SetActive (false);
     
    //EDIT:
    SignIn ();

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("record"))
    {
        record.text = "Record actual: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record");
        Analytics.CustomEvent ("Start Play", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Record", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record")} });

    } else {
            record.text = "Consigue un record!!";
    }

}

public void OnPlay()
{
    ShowAd ();
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Jugar");
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

public void OnArchievements()
{
    if (Social.Active.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.Active.ShowAchievementsUI ();
    } else {
        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            if (success) {
                Social.Active.ShowAchievementsUI ();            
            }
        });
    }

}

public void OnMatching()
{
    if (Social.Active.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.Active.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
    } else {
        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            if (success) {
                Social.Active.ShowLeaderboardUI ();     
            }
        });
    }
}

public void OnExit()
{
    Analytics.CustomEvent ("Stop Play", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Record", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record")} });
    Application.Quit();
}

public void SignIn()
{
    Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate (ProcessAuthentication);
}

public void Later()
{
    signIn.SetActive (false);
}

public void ShowAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
}
//EDIT:
void ProcessAuthentication (bool success) 
{
    if (true == success) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("AUTHENTICATED!");
        if (Social.Active.localUser.authenticated) 
        {
            Social.Active.LoadAchievements (ProcessLoadedAchievements);
            Social.Active.LoadScores (Fireball.GPGSIds.leaderboard_ranking, ProcessLoadedScores );
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("record"))
            {
                Social.Active.ReportScore (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("record"),Fireball.GPGSIds.leaderboard_ranking, (bool report) => { });
            }
            signIn.SetActive (false);
            test.SetActive (true);
        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Failed to authenticate");
        signIn.SetActive (true);
    }
 }
   
  void ProcessLoadedAchievements (IAchievement[] achievements) 
{
    if (achievements.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Error: no achievements found");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("Got " + achievements.Length + " achievements");
    }
}

void ProcessLoadedScores (IScore[] scores) 
{
    if (scores.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Error: no scores found");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("Got " + scores.Length + " scores");
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:
Again in the editor I can't authenticate (in my device it fail too), I really don't understand the cause... Here the debug log (I active it, may can help):

DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.

DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.

DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.

DEBUG: Creating IPlayGamesClient in editor, using DummyClient.

DEBUG: Received method call on DummyClient - using stub implementation.

The last message, is when I try to authenticate, maybe you know the problem with the debug log.

PD: I read de documentation you send me, but is oriented to GameCenter (iOS), but I understand now more thing about that, really thanks.

Again thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you wanted to use achievements and Leaderboards... Check the edit on my original response :)

Comment: Also it would be helpful for you to read the Social class documentation to fully understand it. -> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html Hope this helpe you! :D

Comment: After read the link you send me and with your help, I update the response with my actual situation and my question (create all achievements step by step, etc. Check it please. Thanks.

Comment: What I really don't understand is why fail when I write <PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ()>. Don't I need activate the google platform plugin?? If you could explain that detail too I really thanks you.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I fail in my translation, you say what you're missing, (what I forgot) and I translate what I'm wrong, really sorry, I update de code

Comment: Don't worry I understand. The only thing that you would need to do is set up the plugin on Unity. Window>Google Play Games > Setup> Android setup. It should display a message "installation completed" once you are done. Let me know.

Comment: I did it before, and now again, but nothing change, the same issue.

Comment: can you copy the error from the editor? However, GPGS only works in the device... I don't understand why it fails...

Comment: Quick question, is your app at least in beta or alpha in Google Play store?

Comment: The editor don't show me a error, it just show the log message I put <Failed to authenticate>. But not only in the editor, I test the game in my device, and can't authenticate. And yes, the game is in beta in Google Play Store. I'm publishing the last version right now (the code I show in the comment).

Comment: ok then, my last recommendation is to download all available updates the GPGS doing the following: Windows>Google Play Games> Downloads > Google Play Games SDK (Android). It will open a new dialog. You should install the required elements : 
Google Play Services,
Android Support Library,
Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (Also known as Android Support Repository),
Google Repository,
Android 6.0 (API 23) (this does not affect the min SDK version).


Also watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmHXl-UFTqM

Comment: This video is the first I saw. I really have all package you tell me. I'm so frustrate. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: So... I reviewed my code. I think that all you have to do is to download the app from the store (using alpha/beta). My app can't authenticate when I install it from unity... Did you use a keystore to sign the app? I also have the google debug disabled... I don't know what else to tell you... Sorry.

Comment: Yes I use the keystore. I download from the market, but only appear "conecting to ... " (the dialog) and later it charge, but I can't authenticate, it fails I don't know why... Don't worry, thanks a lot for your help and your time.

Comment: One last thing, did you set the auth2.0 on google developer console? Is not required but it could help.

Comment: Set? I'm not sure but I think I have the first that google give me. I must set to other value? If yes, how I change it and where I see the correct value?

Comment: Follow these steps and let me know-> https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application

Comment: Ah ok, this step I did first when I created the service at first.

Comment: And in the linked apps appears all ok, with a grey check in the oauth2 and other in the publish.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, in the future if you know something leer me know! Really thanks!